# Use slash option in R system function

Tags: r, cmd, system

I am trying to use following cmd function inside R

```
rmdir /q /s myDir
```

I tried:

```
 system("rmdir /q /s myDir")
```

but it returns an error:

```
rmdir: failed to remove '/q': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/s': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove 'public_html/croecon.contentio.biz': Directory not empty
```

How should I use slash option, e.g. /q?

Comment: I don't see how you can get that output. According to the docs https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html `System` does **not** use a shell on Windows. `RmDir` is an internal shell command. The error messages are not those of `RmDir`. Find what you are calling, powershell or a batchfile of that name.?

Comment: I use `rpc` command from `pbdRPC` library but it says it is a wrapper of system function.

Comment: Try this: `system("cmd /C rmdir /q /s myDir")`

Comment: In the end, I try to use bash version and it worked: `rm -rf directoryname`

Answer (score 1):

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2") 
Set objEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace")
Do
    Set objReceivedEvent = objEvents.NextEvent
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process where ProcessID=" & objReceivedEvent.ProcessID)
    For Each objItem in colItems
        wscript.echo objItem.name & " " & objItem.ProcessID & " " & objItem.CommandLine    
    Next
Loop
```

Then type in a command prompt

```
cscript //nologo C:\folder\MonitorProcessCreation.vbs
```

This will monitor what starts when you run your command.